# How do I fade in a changing value in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am building a real-time data monitoring app using React. If a data value changes, I want to highlight it by fading in the new value. I'm having trouble getting it to work. Here's what I've tried:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class ObsValue extends React.PureComponent {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {delta: 0};
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
        const delta = this.props.obsValue - newProps.obsValue;
        this.setState(() => {return {delta};});
    }

    render() {
        const str_val = this.props.obsValue.toString();

        // If there is a difference, do a fade in to the new value.
        const cn = this.state.delta ? "fadeIn" : "";

        return (<div className={cn}>{str_val}</div>);
    }
}
```

This works the first time, but, unfortunately, not thereafter. Presumably the problem is that after the first time the component has been built, so the fade in is complete.

How do I get it to fade in with every changing value?

One thing I tried was to toggle a `key` whenever `delta` was non-zero. This signaled to React that this was a "different" component, so it did the fade in. But, this seems like a bit of a hack. There must be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Hve you looked at the react [Animation addons](https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html) to see if there is something there to help you?

Answer (score -1):

In theory this should work, having fadeIn as a boolean in your state that will be set to true if the new props you send to your component is different from the previous ones. I should trigger a re-render and your fadeIn class should be shown on each render. Hope it helps.

EDIT: Added a timeout in the setState() callback to set state fadeIn back to false after 0.5 second if the updated props is different from the new props in `componentWillReceiveProps()`.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fadeIn: false
    };
}

componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (this.props.obsValue !== newProps.obsValue) {
      this.setState({ fadeIn: true },
      () => setTimeout(() => this.setState({ fadeIn: false }), 500));
    }
}

render() {
    const str_val = this.props.obsValue.toString();

    return (<div className={this.state.fadeIn ? 'fadeIn' : ''}>{str_val}</div>);
}
```

Comment: This is essentially what I am doing. It doesn't work for the reason I outlined in my original question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: In your example you check if this.state.diff is truthy but this.state.diff is never set unless that part of the code is missing from your example.

Comment: True enough. That's a typo introduced when I simplified the actual code. I've corrected the example.

Comment: I added a change to my answer, maybe it feels hacky aswell but it should solve the issue? :) Its in `componentDidUpdate()`

Comment: That does not work either. [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/tkeffer/yww7ae6q/).  I suspect it's the same issue: the component is only built once (the first time), so the fade in is complete.

Comment: Ahh I see I messed up the setTimeout(), check the updated answer again now it works :)

Comment: check https://jsfiddle.net/yww7ae6q/15/, this was hard to figure out :D

Comment: I dunno. Your solution depends on picking a magic wait time, long enough for the browser to finish rendering, then removing the fadeIn. How long is long enough?

It's working on my Mac, but on a slower machine it might not.

Comment: Here's a solution that depends on toggling a `key` value. It works, and is not subject to a race condition. Still feels like a bit of a kludge, though.  https://jsfiddle.net/tkeffer/yww7ae6q/17/